# Please help me find the bug in my Bootstrap 3 nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The collapsed nav bar (at small window sizes) no long functions.  Clicking on the nav icon doesn't pop up a dropdown nav.  You can view the site and its source here:  http://www.clearsoftinc.com/Clearsoft/public_html/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `data-target` on your button `navbar-toggle` should be

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse"
```

It was previously `.nav-collapse`

Easy to miss with so many similar classes in bootstrap!

Answer (score 0):

You have JavaScript error:

```
GET http://www.clearsoftinc.com/Clearsoft/public_html/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 404 (Not Found)
```

You must include this file.

Comment: Why do i have that js error? My project has "jquery-1.10.2.min.js" and  there are no explicit calls to a "jquery-1.10.2.min.map" anywhere.  I did notice this in the jquery source:  "//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map"